# C: Initializing size+1 of an array?

Tags: arrays, element

What happens if I do something like this?

```
int a[10];
a[10] = 1;
```

The array elements goes from 0-9 so I am basically initializing an integer outside its size. Would this result in an error and does the same error, if there is, apply to a char array as well? I know that you declare a[size+1] to leave an element for the null value, but that's pretty much it...

EDIT: Would this lead to anything else other than a buffer overflow?

Comment: 1) You might want to add the language that you're using, and 2) have you tried it?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that. Yes, I tried running it and it gave me no errors, so I am curious if it will give me an error later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is undefined and might go from "nothing happens" over "a solid crash a few moment later" to "totally weird Heisenbug". Its also quite likely effected by compilerflags.

What really happens though is that you place the array on the stack and then write into "something else" below it. That "something else" can vary greatly and only be determined if you look at the generated assembly code.

[int a[10]]
[previous variables, possibly even return address]

In short: dont do it, and try using compiler settings that enable stack checks and warnings.
If you happen to use a recent gcc or clang you should get a warning that you access out-of-bounds, and you can also enable "sanitizers" which will warn about such accesses as they happen when your program runs.